# Styling a component on basis of arguments passed from another component

Tags: angular

I have a component called file-uploader component which look's like following.
html:

```
<label class="uploader" ondragover="return false;"
[class.loaded]="loaded" 
[style.outlineColor]="dragging ? activeColor : baseColor"
(dragenter)="handleDragEnter()"
(dragleave)="handleDragLeave()"
(drop)="handleDrop($event)">
<span *ngIf="!imageLoaded">{{label}}</span>
<img 
    [src]="imageSrc" 
    (load)="handleImageLoad()" 
    [class.loaded]="imageLoaded"/>
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
    (change)="handleInputChange($event)">
```

and css looks like this.

```
/* File Uploader Styles  */
.uploader {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
 /* height: 200px;*/
 width: 230.5px;
  height: 118.5px;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  outline: 3px dashed #ccc;
  outline-offset: 5px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;

  input {
  display: none;
  }

  img {
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*z-index: -1;*/
  }

  .icon {
    color: #eee;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 5em;
  }

  span{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
  }

  img.loaded {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}

.uploader img,
.uploader .icon {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.uploader,
.uploader span {
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}
```

I can call this component from any other component in following way.

```
<app-file-uploader  [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader>
```

How can I change the styles of app-file-uploader when calling it from a component on basis of some condition or value of some variable?

Comment: What style do you want to change in what way depending on what condition?

Comment: I want to change the width and height of uploader class when some boolean is true or false. I don't know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't provide any means of modifying CSS, but you can just add/remove a class to apply different styles depending on that class:

```
.uploader {
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  ...
  height: 200px;
  width: 230.5px;
  ...
}

.uploader.other {
  height: 400px;
  width: 461px;
}
```

```
<app-file-uploader class="uploader" [class.other]="someBoolean"  [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader>
```

Comment: can you kindly explain it a bit! what is uploader.other and [class.other]?

Comment: It's just a random name I chose. `[class.other]="someBoolean"` adds/removes `class="other"` depending on the value of `@Input() someBoolean:bool;` and the style `.uploader.other { ... }` overrides the same styles in `.uploader {...}` when `class="other"` is added, because of higher specifity.

Comment: i have added @Input() type:boolean; in file-uploader component and 
.uploader.other{
    width: 250;
    height: 118;
  }
in it's styles.
Then I added this component in another component in following way: 
<app-file-uploader class="uploader" [class.other]="true"  [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader>

But it is not working!!

Comment: `[class.other]="true"` should be `[class.other]="type"`

Comment: and where type is supposed to be set true or false?

Comment: `<app-file-uploader  [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader [type]="true">`. This sets `@Input() type:boolean;` to `true`.

Comment: Setting it to `true` statically like in your above example should also have set the hight and width to `118` and `250`. I can't tell from here why it didn't. You can check in the browsers devtools if the clases `uploader` and `other` where added and which styles are applied.

Comment: <app-file-uploader class="uploader" [class.other]="type" [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader [type]="true"> is not working..It gives some parse error

Comment: Sorry, it should be `<app-file-uploader [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"  [type]="true"></app-file-uploader>`